# CUrl failing when using it to build a dll in x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, curl, libcurl

In one of my **dll** application which I'm developing using **(VS2010)C++** in my **x64** machine, I'm using `CUrl` to read a `HTTPS` file. The application fails in the line, `curl_easy_init()`, when executing the **dll**. When I develop an exe instead of a **dll**, its working fine. When I ran a Dependency Walker on the **dll**, it says *gpsvc.dll is missing*. But the same **x32** build dll is not giving me this error. Please let me know any solution for the same. Please help me on the same. Thank you.

Comment: gpsvc.dll is a side-by-side thing that isn't reliably checked by dependency walker (which is a huge shame on Microsoft). The problem is likely to be elsewhere. Do you not have a 64-bit version of curl.dll to use?

Comment: Hi, Yes I'm using proper x64 Curl.dll. Please help me with this.

Comment: sorry - the problem is too vague. Try the debug version built from sources and step into the function to see where it goes wrong or what error codes it returns.

Comment: Do you see any other way to read a HTTPS file other than using cUrl?